# How to add incoming characters from UART to a string?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

How do I add up incoming individual characters over UART to form a string?

For exmaple:

The characters from UART are printed in following format:

```
\x02
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
\X03
\x02
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
\x03
```

and I would like output to be something like:

```
1234567
abcdefg
```

I have tried this so far:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',38400)
txt = ""

ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while 1:
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    data_raw = ser.read(1)
    while 1:
        if data_raw !='\x02' or data_raw !='\x03':
            txt += data_raw
        elif data_raw == '\x03':
            break
    print txt
```

Any ideas on how to do that? I am getting no output using this.

Comment: Those should be backslashes, not forward slashes

Comment: What output do you get? How does it differ from what you want? Why do you think that is?

Comment: Do you actually want the string? Or are you just trying to get it to print right?

Comment: Yeah I would like a string with each packet in one line, thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to call `inWaiting`: [`read`](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read) will block until data is available unless you explicitly set a read timeout. Secondly, if you do insist on using it, keep in mind that the function `inWaiting` has been replaced by the property [`in_waiting`](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting).

The string `/x03` is a 4-character string containing all printable characters. The string `\x03`, on the other hand, contains only a single non printable character with ASCII code 3. *Backslash* is the escape character in Python strings. `\x` followed by two digits is an ASCII character code. Please use backslashes where they belong. This is the immediate reason you are not seeing output: the four character string can never appear in a one-character read.

That being out of the way, the most important thing to remember is to clear your buffer when you encounter a terminator character. Let's say you want to use the inefficient method of adding to your string in place. When you reach `\x03`, you should print `txt` and just reset it back to `''` instead of breaking out of the loop. A better way might be to use [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray), which is a mutable sequence. Keep in mind also that `read` returns bytes, not strings in Python 3.x. This means that you should be decoding the result if you want text: `txt = txt.decode('ascii')`.

I would suggest a further improvement, and create an infinite generator function to split your steam into strings. You could use that generator to print the strings or do anything else you wanted with them:

```
def getstrings(port):
    buf = bytearray()
    while True:
        b = port.read(1)
        if b == b'\x02':
            del buf[:]
        elif b == b'\x03':
            yield buf.decode('ascii')
        else:
            buf.append(b)

for item in getstring(Serial(...)):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, it did worked

buf.clear() didn't worked for me. I had to change it for del buf[:]

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way that I think would help you a bit

```
l = []
while 1:
    data_raw = ser.read(1)
    if data_raw !='/x02' or data_raw !='/x03':
        l.append(data_raw)
    elif data_raw == '/x03':
        txt = "-".join(l)
        print txt
```

I begin by creating an empty list and each time you receive a new raw_data. you append it to the list. Once you reach your ending character, you create your string and print it.

I took the liberty of removing one of the loop here to give you a simpler approach. The code will not break by itself at the end (just add a break after the print if you want to). It will print out the result whenever you reach the ending character and then wait for a next data stream to start.

If you want to see an intermediate result, you can print out each data_raw and could add right after a print of the currently joined list.

Be sure to  set a timeout value to None when you open your port. That way, you will simply wait to receive one bit, process it and then return to read one bit at a time.

```
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=38400, timeout=None)
```

http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html for mor information on that.

Comment: Looks like txt = ''.join(l) is not working for some reason. No output at all. Instead if I use print l then I do see the output.

Comment: Looks like it is not matching with '/x03' for some reason.

Comment: I moved l=[] in while and now I am getting something like this, if I print l but nothing on text.

['\x02']
['9']
['L']
['0']
['0']
['1']
['2']
['5']
['0']
['0']
['1']
['\x03']
['\x02']
['9']
['H']
['1']
['1']
['0']
['5']
['9']
['0']
['0']
['1']
['\x03']

Comment: 1) it seems that you try to match /x03 with \x03
2) try out txt = "-".join(l) the dash is a delimiter between character. Could be a space could be something else entirely if you want to (empty string would be "".join(l). 3) don't move the initial array inside the while otherwise you will override it with an empty array at each loop.

Comment: you need to clear the list after the terminator is encountered

Comment: It is *utterly impossible* for a single character read from the serial port to  be equal to the 4-character strings `'/x02'` or `'/x03'`.  You almost certainly mean `'\x02'` and `'\x03'`, which are single characters expressed using a hexadecimal escape sequence.

Comment: @jasonharper. I addressed that ad nauseum in my answer